# What is the advantage of using FAST_FORWARD for defining a cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-cursor

What is the advantage of using FAST_FORWARD for defining a cursor? Is it better for performance? why?

Comment: There's some great analysis & detail at https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/why-does-fast_forward-make-some-cursors-so-much-faster/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The definition from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258831(SQL.80).aspx) is:

> Specifies a FORWARD_ONLY, READ_ONLY
>   cursor **with performance optimizations
>   enabled**. FAST_FORWARD cannot be
>   specified if SCROLL or FOR_UPDATE is
>   also specified. FAST_FORWARD and
>   FORWARD_ONLY are mutually exclusive;
>   if one is specified the other cannot
>   be specified.

I've boldened the key bit. It can support these "performance optimisations" because it does not need to support multi-direction iterating through the cursor (FORWARD_ONLY) and does not support modifications (READ_ONLY).

Of course, if you don't really need to use a cursor at all - then using a cursor even with this option is not going to perform as well . If you can do the same task using a set-based approach, do that instead - this is the bit I really wanted to stress.

Answer (score 13):

**FAST_FORWARD** - specifies that cursor will be FORWARD_ONLY and READ_ONLY cursor. The FAST_FORWARD cursors produce the least amount of overhead on SQL Server.

Source: [Click Here](http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/General/UseCursor.htm)

Answer (score 4):

The `FAST_FORWARD` specifies that it's `FORWARD_ONLY` and `READ_ONLY`, meaning it uses the least amount of server resources to handle it...so yes, for performance.

[MSDN has a full rundown of cursor options here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx).

> **FAST_FORWARD**
>
> - Specifies a FORWARD_ONLY, READ_ONLY cursor with performance optimizations enabled. FAST_FORWARD cannot be specified if SCROLL or FOR_UPDATE is also specified.

Answer (score 3):

Just keep in mind that FAST_FORWARD is DYNAMIC ... FORWARD_ONLY you can use with a STATIC cursor.

Try using it on the Halloween problem to see what happens !!!

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Funcionarios') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE Funcionarios
GO

CREATE TABLE Funcionarios(ID          Int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
                          ContactName Char(7000),
                          Salario     Numeric(18,2));
GO

INSERT INTO Funcionarios(ContactName, Salario) VALUES('Fabiano', 1900)
INSERT INTO Funcionarios(ContactName, Salario) VALUES('Luciano',2050)
INSERT INTO Funcionarios(ContactName, Salario) VALUES('Gilberto', 2070)
INSERT INTO Funcionarios(ContactName, Salario) VALUES('Ivan', 2090)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_Salario ON Funcionarios(Salario)
GO

-- Halloween problem, will update all rows until then reach 3000 !!!
UPDATE Funcionarios SET Salario = Salario * 1.1
  FROM Funcionarios WITH(index=ix_Salario)
 WHERE Salario < 3000
GO

-- Simulate here with all different CURSOR declarations
-- DYNAMIC update the rows until all of then reach 3000
-- FAST_FORWARD update the rows until all of then reach 3000
-- STATIC update the rows only one time. 

BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE TMP_Cursor CURSOR DYNAMIC 
--DECLARE TMP_Cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
--DECLARE TMP_Cursor CURSOR STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
    FOR SELECT ID 
          FROM Funcionarios WITH(index=ix_Salario)
         WHERE Salario < 3000

OPEN TMP_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM TMP_Cursor INTO @ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Funcionarios WITH(index=ix_Salario)

  UPDATE Funcionarios SET Salario = Salario * 1.1 
   WHERE ID = @ID

  FETCH NEXT FROM TMP_Cursor INTO @ID
END

CLOSE TMP_Cursor
DEALLOCATE TMP_Cursor

SELECT * FROM Funcionarios

ROLLBACK TRAN
GO
```

Comment: FAST_FORWARD is not always DYNAMIC. It will switch to STATIC if STATIC is a better plan.

Comment: @Ahmed True, but FORWARD_ONLY STATIC is guaranteed to be static, whereas with FAST_FORWARD it's out of your control

Answer (score 2):

(I know this is old, but for posterity)

Just to expatiate the "fast_forward" and "forward_only/read_only" cursors, the difference is in cursor plan usage.

`FO/RO` cursors always use a dynamic query plan - and for most applications, this is sufficient. 
However, even a good dynamic plan is almost never as good as a static plan.

`FF` cursors will use a static plan if it's better, and won't ever downgrade cursor plans (mostly what the "...with performance optimizations enabled." is referring to).

Generally dynamic plans are more optimal for small result set ("low-goal") cursors, and vice-versa for static.