# Dynamic query with table variable to loop through all tables to update in a database

Tags: t-sql

I working on a SQL query to update a list of tables and columns in a database. Any suggestions are welcome.

I am using information_schema.tables and information_schema.columns, lookup table, and a table variable. However, I am having an issue updating.

I started with the join to ensure I am matching the right table and column needed to the lookup table.

I need to loop through and update tables where matched to the objectname if table.column.

i was trying to use a cursor but did some research and thought table variable may work better for optimization and performance.
I declared my variables and create a table variable but it is still not updating. I started with the below query after I created and populated my table variable.

I tried different ways with a cursor and table variable but I am not getting it right to complete the update.

```
'Select l.objectname, l.fieldname, l.newpvalue, l.oldpvalue from lookup_table 1 inner join information_schema.tables t
                 on l.objectname = t.table_name
                inner join information_schema.columns c
                  on l.fieldname = c.column_name and l.objectname 
                                 = c.table_name'
```

Here is the new update that I am attempting to parameterized

```
SELECT 'UPDATE' + I.TABLE_NAME + 'SET C.COLUMN_NAME = 
                                        CASE 
                                            WHEN TP.[listValue] = TP.[OldValue]
                                            WHEN TP.[listValue] != TP.[OldValue] 
                                                        THEN SET TP.NOTES = C.COLUMN_NAME '-' TP.[OldValue]
                                                        AND SET C.COLUMN_NAME = NULL
                                        END
        FROM 
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES I INNER JOIN [dbo].[tpRef] tp
                                    ON I.TABLE_NAME = tp.ObjectName
                                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                                    ON tp.[FieldName] = C.COLUMN_NAME
                                        AND tp.[ObjectName] = C.TABLE_NAME
                                LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C2
                                    ON tp.[FieldName] = C2.COLUMN_NAME
                                    AND C2.COLUMN_NAME = 'NOTES'
        WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'base table'
                        AND tp.ObjectName = 'table name'
                        AND tp.FieldName = 'table field'
                        AND tp.[listValue] = 'List'
```

Comment: are you indicating that i should use a cursor with table variable?

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to use table variable but are you indicating to use both a table variable and cursor?

When I run the below is takes a long time.

----UPDATE TABLE AND COLUMN FOUND

```
SELECT @STRUPDSQL =
         'UPDATE' + 'I.TABLE_NAME' + 'SET C.COLUMN_NAME = 
                                        CASE 
                                            WHEN TP.[PicklistValue] = TP.[OldValue]
                                            WHEN TP.[PicklistValue] != TP.[OldValue] 
                                                        THEN SET TP.NOTES = C.COLUMN_NAME - TP.[OldValue]
                                                        AND SET C.COLUMN_NAME = NULL
                                        END
        FROM 
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES I INNER JOIN @TBLS T
                                            ON I.TABLE_NAME = T.v_TABLENAME

        WHERE T.v_TABLENAME =@l_TBLNM   AND T.v_COLUMNNAME =@l_COLNNM                   

'
    SET @I = @I + 1
    END
```

I have it working but the value that I want to update with is being read as a column name and not the column data value.

IF  quotename(@COLNAME) IS NOT NULL

```
        BEGIN
            SET @SQL = 'UPDATE ' + quotename(@TABLENAME) + ' SET ' + quotename(@COLNAME) + ' = ' +'"' + @TVALUE + '"' + ' ' + 'WHERE ' + quotename(@COLNAME) + '= AccountSource'
        END
```

Comment: i realized i need to go back to include a temp table or table variable like i had in my original code to successfully update the value in the table that I am passing.

Answer (score 0):

not a working cursor, needs the query to fill out the needed columns to populate the variables.

```
declare 
     @table_name varchar(128) 
    ,@schema_name varchar(128) -- dbo is the default schema, if custom make sure query returns the correct schema
    ,@update_column varchar(128) 
    ,@update_data varchar(1024)
    ,@where_column varchar(128)
    ,@where_data varchar(1024)
    ,@s varchar(max);
declare x cursor local fast_forward 
for
/*
 insert your query returning desired values to be looped through.
 */
select 1,2,3,4,5,6 --6 variables to populate. delete this line when you get your query written above :)
open x;
fetch next from x into @table_name,@update_column,@schema_name,@update_data,@where_column,@where_data;

while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        set @s = '
            update ' + quotename(@schema_name) + '.' + quotename(@table_name) + ' 
            set  ' + quotename(@update_column) + ' = ''' + @update_data + ''' where ' + quotename(@where_column) + ' = ''' + @where_data + ''';
            '
        begin try
            --to execute it, you can use exec()
            exec(@s); 
            --to print out the string so you can read and or copy/paste to text execution use print()
            print(@s);
            /* 
                I would recommend print(@s); until you have all your bugs worked out.
                process the updates manually from the printed statements to verify syntax correctness and results
             */
        end try
        begin catch
            print error_message()
        end catch;
        -- this list of variables must match the first "fetch next" and all be declared and returned in the "for" query of the cursor.
        -- those that are not must be set inside the cursor by queries, calculations or hardcoded.
        fetch next from x into @table_name,@update_column,@schema_name,@update_data,@where_column,@where_data;
    end

close x;
deallocate x;
```

Cursor used is
[Fast_forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280452/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-fast-forward-for-defining-a-cursor)(SO answer) = (read_only and forward_only)
[Local](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options)(cursor performance breakdown) = local in scope, only valid within scope.

I still can't bring myself to use the information_schema views...

Comment: thank you but i need update the table and column data value. I am using a lookup to pass the table name, column name and value that i need to compare to determine value update. I will remove the information you are pulling that i do not need and try using this one. I am getting an syntax with the dynamic sql i am using.

Comment: the issue I have is executing an update statement in the set query where I need to pass tablename and columnname

Comment: modified the answer so that it's closer to what your final result needs, still need to populate the cursor with a query returning the needed data for the updates.

Comment: thank i actually did what you modified to on yesterday. It was updating but the value was not correct. So I am testing again this morning but it is not updating at all now so tracing through to see what changed.